# Assign FBA role in SharePoint 2013 Group programmatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, spgroup

I have created a SharePoint group programmatically. I want to assign a FBA role in that created group. I am able to add SharePoint/FBA users but not able to add a FBA role. Kindly let me know, how can I achieve this scenario?